# How to open 1000 simultaneous client process for a localhost server?

Tags: c, linux, server

I have a server program running.
I want to connect 1000 clients to it and observe how the server is working. I also want to save the output to a file for analyzing.
My server is just an echo server.

Comment: What type of server? http?

Comment: It is just a program in C created using sockets. uses tcp connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use netcat:

```
for ii in {1..1000}; do
  (echo "testing"; sleep 5; echo "goodbye") | nc localhost 12345 > out.$ii &
done
wait # for all to finish
```

Comment: Thank you.How do i output the results to a file?

Comment: @PragyaDaga: I updated my answer to include writing to one file for each client.  Mixing them might be problematic because they could interleave, so I just write to separate files and you can `cat out.*` at the end if you want.

Comment: You're welcome.  If an answer here solved your problem, please do click the "checkmark" on the left of the answer to "accept" it.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.